# How do I get my sounds working?

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa, asus, soundcard

I purchased an **Asus Vivobook Pro K6500ZH** PC a few days ago and I installed Ubuntu on it,
Everything works fine beside my sounds, for some reason I can't hear any sound.

I've tried many things which didn't work like playing with alsamixer and so on. I only found one solution that works for me on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHBK4ix8BCg&t=52s&ab_channel=MhammedElAsaad) which uses the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0x1b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x4a4b
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x500 0xf
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 0x477 0x74
```

Everything seems good until I reboot my PC and I need to run the script over again in order to make the sounds work, it's very annoying.

What can be the reason that I cannot hear any sounds and how can I fix it without running that script whenever I reboot my PC?

**I have a soundcard**: HDA Intel PCH

**Chip**: Realtek ALC294

**Output of the**: `sudo lshw -c sound` command

```
*-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: card1
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D7p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D8p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D9p
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:86080000-86083fff
  *-usb:2
       description: Video
       product: USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 F
       vendor: Sonix Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 9
       bus info: usb@3:9
       logical name: input9
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
       version: 0.03
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       logical name: card0
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D10p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D11p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D12p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D13p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D14p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D15p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D16p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D17p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:188 memory:6037288000-603728bfff memory:6037000000-60370fffff
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute `sudo modprobe -v snd-hda-intel` in your terminal? I hope this solves the issue. If not, could you please share the output of `sudo lshw -c sound`?

Comment: @nicdm I shared the output in the above post, can you please help?